# Best way to serve image+html content to html page using servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I'm trying to update a particular 'div' with profile pic and some html content without refreshing the whole page when the user successfully authenticated.

I
1) Stored the profile pic while user registration process to database( I could save it to a file system, but here my requirement is to store it in database blob)
2) Could able to retrieve image as a binary stream from database and display image alone(without any html content) to html page

I went through a couple of Answers in stackoverflow, they say we can't serve image+html content to the same webpage('div' in my case) from one servlet!

Help me to with how to serve image+html content to update just a 'div' of html page?

Answer (score 0):

How about writing 2 servlets, one to take in the image and write it to the database and another one to get the image and pass it back in the response output stream which you can call from the webpage via an ajax call.

Comment: I did exactly the same., my question is in the 2nd servlet(where you are responding with image) how to respond with both image and some HTML content'?

Answer (score 0):

Get the output stream of the HttpServletResponse object passed into your servlet and use write method to pass back your image. I would encode your image to base 64 and wrap it with some html.

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
response.getWriter().println("html and base64 string");
response.getWriter().close();
}
```

Comment: when you make an ajax call to this servlet you can take the html and base64 string repsonse and dynamically embed it in your webpage with JavaScript or JQuery